# Trouble with error placement jquery validate

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I have several different fieldsets in a long form each one structured slightly differently. I have one that I can't get the error message to show up

HTML:

```
<form>
    <fieldset id="Initial>
         <div class="section">
             <h3>Do you wish to add <span>Market Depth,</span> the ability to view <span>Nasdaq Level II data</span> and <span>futures market depth?</span></h3>
                    <span class="row"><label><input type="checkbox" name="MKDPT" id="MKDPT">Add Market Depth</label></span>
          </div>
     </fieldset>
</form>
```

I want to inject the error element "`p`" after the `span` class row

js:

```
....
errorElement: "p",
errorPlacement: function(error, element) 
{
    if( element.closest("#final_step").length ) {
        error.appendTo( element.parent("li"));
    } else if( element.closest("#EX_AGREEMENT").length ) {
        element.closest('li').after(error);
    } else if( element.closest("#Initial").length ) {
        error.insertAfter( element.parent("div"));
    } else {
        error.insertAfter(element.parent("li"));
    }
},
....
```

should note the input `#MKDPT` is getting the error class

Comment: @Andrew - sorry for the spelling errors, been going 19 hrs straight feel like im in a coma. thx for the hand

Comment: @Andrew - any idea why it's not working as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're just one character off. Your `errorPlacement` function is being entered and entering the following `if` block:

```
/*Snip */
else if( element.closest("#Initial").length ) {
        error.insertAfter( element.parent("div"));
    }
```

The problem is `element.parent("div")` yields an empty jQuery object, since [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent) only looks at the *immediate* parent of the context element.

If you replace that line with `element.parents("div")` (**note** [`parents`](http://api.jquery.com/parents), not `parent`) you should be fine:

```
$("form").validate({
    errorElement: "p",
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if (element.closest("#final_step").length) {
            error.appendTo(element.parent("li"));
        } else if (element.closest("#EX_AGREEMENT").length) {
            element.closest('li').after(error);
        } else if (element.closest("#Initial").length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parents("div"));
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent("li"));
        }
    }
});
```

Here it is working (assuming the checkbox is a required element): http://jsfiddle.net/uLRw9/

Comment: @Dirty Bird Design: There's an `</h3>`, right before the `span.row`, I just moved it down in the fiddle.

Comment: got it man, thx. was "error.insertAfter(element.parents("span"));

Comment: @Dirty Bird Design: Awesome, glad I could help.